# Eclipse- moves my button labels right

Tags: android, eclipse, button, label

as You can see on the screen shot: all labels on my buttons in Android layout designing are moved right. Of course they are correct when using emulator, but this irritates me during designing layout.
Whan can I do to change this?!
                       [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GskaD.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it myself: it requires to restart Eclipse, and if that doesn't help: restart computer and Eclipse ;-)